# Clause Where condition is null doesnt work in the formtype builder

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

```
namespace Quindimotos\ProyectoBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class asignarEmpleadoAServicioType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('ciudad', 'entity', array(
            'empty_value' => 'Seleccione Empleado',
            'class' => 'QuindimotosProyectoBundle:empleado',
            'property_path' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                                ->join('e.cargo', 'c')
                                ->from('QuindimotosProyectoBundle:Revision', 'r')
                                ->join('r.empleado', 'e1')
                                ->where('c.nombre =:cargo and r.empleado is not null')
                                ->setParameter('cargo', 'tecnico');
            }
        ))
        ->add('Revision', 'entity', array(
            'empty_value' => 'Seleccione Revision Disponible',
            'class' => 'QuindimotosProyectoBundle:revision',
            'property_path' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')

                                ->where('r.recividopor is  null');

            }));

    }
    public function getName() {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
```

In the next line I don't know  why it doesn't work

```
->where('c.nombre =:cargo and r.empleado is null')
```

The clause where is ok but the condition "is null" doesn't show nothing but I know that there is something to show.

And in this line this clause where is ok and "is null" is working well

```
->where('r.recividopor is  null');
```

Someone can say me what is the matter here.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing a value with a "null" value using regular operators will result in an empty resultset, because the comparasion will not result a boolean value (instead will return NULL)

You have to avoid the comparasion, one way is : `SELECT IFNULL(e.cargo,0) AS e.cargo` then you can use it in where clause `c.nomber = e.cargo`.